# Некорректно парсится дата

Tags: c#

У меня проблема с парсингом даты из строки в Datetime формат, когда я использую, напр. 01.05.2017. Пример: у меня есть дата `"01.05.2017"` я парсю её из строки в нужный формат даты и отнимаю один день, чтобы получить предыдущий, однако вместо 30.04.2017 получаю 31.12.2016, а при преобразовании обратно в строку - вообще 31.05.16. В чём может быть проблема, тем более, что с другими датами всё в порядке? Только с первыми числами.
Мой код:

```
DateTime temp_Till = DateTime.ParseExact(bsObj.till_date, "dd.mm.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddDays(-1);
bsObj.from_date = temp_Till.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Если бы вы использовали дебаггер, потом начали бы искать место ошибки, то увидели бы, что ещё ДО ЭТАПА AddDays(-1) у вас парсинг даёт дату `01.01.2017 0:05:00`. Разумеется, вычтя из этой даты один день вы получите 31.12.2016. Проблема -- в некорректном парсинге даты: не dd.mm.yyyy, а dd.MM.yyyy Вопрос -  закрыть, "вызван опечаткой".

Comment: `mm` - минуты. `MM` - месяцы. Замените маленькие буквы на большие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы вы использовали дебаггер, потом начали бы искать место ошибки, то увидели бы, что ещё ДО ЭТАПА AddDays(-1) у вас парсинг даёт дату `01.01.2017 0:05:00`.

Разумеется, вычтя из этой даты один день вы получите 31.12.2016.

Проблема -- в некорректном парсинге даты: не `dd.mm.yyyy`, а `dd.MM.yyyy`, см. [форматы дат в документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Вопрос -  закрыть, т.к. "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой".